# How do I properly create an img element in javascript without it not recognizing the image and reading "Object HTML image" in place of the image

Tags: javascript, image

### Where did I got wrong I'm trying to create an img element in javascript, nest inside of a button element, and also set onmouseover and onmouseout to the img element which will change images when the event is detected.

Here is my Javascript (ps I know I repeat some functions more than once I didn't know how to simplify them properly)
I also tried to create the img attributes 2 different ways

```
moveImg = document.createElement("img");
    removeImg.innerHTML = "< img src='icons/trash.png' id='dormant' onmouseover='newTrashPicture()' onmouseout='oldTrashPicture()'/>"

var createImg = document.createElement("img");
createImg.src="icons/check.png";
createImg.setAttribute("id" , "dormant2");
createImg.onmouseover = newCheckPicture();
createImg.onmouseout = oldCheckPicture();


document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',function() {
var value = document.getElementById('item').value;
If(value) addItemTodo(value); {

}
});

function addItemTodo(text) {
var list = document.getElementById('todo');

var item = document.createElement("li");
item.innerText = text;

var buttons = document.createElement('div');
buttons.classList.add('buttons');

var removePic = document.createElement('button');
removePic.classList.add('remove');
removePic.innerHTML = removeImg;

var complete = document.createElement('button');
complete.classList.add('complete');
complete.innerHTML = createImg;

buttons.appendChild(removePic);
buttons.appendChild(complete);
item.appendChild(buttons);
list.appendChild(item);
}


function newTrashPicture() {
document.getElementById("dormant").src="icons/redtrash.png";
}

function oldTrashPicture() {
document.getElementById("dormant").src="icons/trash.png";
}

function newCheckPicture() {
document.getElementById("dormant2").src="icons/greencirclecheck.png";
}

function oldCheckPicture() {
document.getElementById("dormant2").src="icons/check.png";
```

### }

---

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Todo List App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?     family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activiy..." id="item">
<button id="add"><img id="img1" src="icons/plus.png"></button>
</header>
<div class="container">
<ul class="todo" id="todo">
<li>
This is an item
<div class="buttons">
<button class="remove"><img src="icons/trash.png" id="dormant" onmouseover="newTrashPicture()" onmouseout="oldTrashPicture()"></button>
<button class="complete"><img src="icons/check.png" id="dormant2" onmouseover="newCheckPicture()" onmouseout="oldCheckPicture()"></button>

</div>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="todo" id="completed">
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascript/main.js">.     </script>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
background:#edf0f1;
padding:80px 0 0 0;
margin:0px;
}

body input button {
font-family:'Roboto'sans-serif;
}

header {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:fixed;
padding:15px;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:5;
background:#25b99a;
box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15);
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;

webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */


}

header input {
width:100%;
height:50px;
float:left;
color:#fff;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:400;
text-indent:18px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-right:60px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:0px;
background:rgba(225,225,225,0.2);
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:25px;
border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
border:0px;
box-shadow:none;
outline:none;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-ms-appearance:none;
-o-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
} 

header input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

header input:-moz-input-placeholder {
color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

header input::-moz-input-placeholder {
color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

header input:-ms-input-placeholder {
color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

header button {
width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
top:15px;
right:15px;
z-index:2;
border-radius:25px;
background:#fff;
border:0px;
box-shadow:none;
outline:none;
cursor:pointer;

-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-ms-appearance:none;
-o-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
}
header button:hover {
background:#fcfcfc;
}
header button:active {
background:#bcbcbc;
}

header button #img1 {
width:16px;
height:16px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-8px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:-8px;
}

.container {
width:100%;
float:left;
padding:15px;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

ul.todo {
width:100%;
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
-webkit-margin-before:0px;
-webkit-margin-after: 0px;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start:0px;
}

ul.todo li {
width:100%;
min-height:50px;
float:left;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:500;
color:#400;
line-height:22px; 
background:#fff;
border-radius:5px;
position:relative;
box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(44,62,80,0.10);
margin:0 0 10px 0;
padding:14px 100px 14px 14px;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

ul.todo li:last-of-type {
margin:0;
}

ul.todo li .buttons {
width:100px;
height:50px;

position: absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}

ul.todo li .buttons button {
width:50px;
height:50px;
float:left;
background: none;
position:relative;
border:0px;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
padding:0 0 0 0;

-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-ms-appearance:none;
-o-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
}
ul.todo li .buttons button:last-of-type:before {
content:"";
width:1px;
height:30px;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:0px;
background:#edf0f1;
}
ul.todo li .buttons button img {
width:22px;
height:22px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-11px 0 0 -11px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#dormant2:hover {
width:36px;
height:36px;
margin:-18px 0 0 -18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is append the image to your button element instead of setting it as an innerHTML propertie.

Replace :

```
removePic.innerHTML = removeImg;
```

with :

```
removePic.appendChild(removeImg);
```

Same with the complete button.

The innerHTML propertie accepts string as an argument, but your are passing it an object.

This does not work :

```
var removeImg = document.createElement("img");
removePic.innerHTML = removeImg;
```

But this does :

```
var removeImg = "<img src='icons/trash.png' id='dormant'>";
removePic.innerHTML = removeImg;
```

So either you :

- Append the object
- Set the innerHTML with a string